# Drop similar column numerical value match pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, data-science

For the pandas dataframe below, I want to remove all rows where `video` and `view` values are equal and two of the four columns, `left, width, top, height` are within +-1 of each other. So in the example below, the second row, (width, height) is (20, 14), third row, (width, height) is (21, 15), so one of these two rows should be dropped because those rows share +-1 values in `width` and `height` column.

```
view     video                      left    width  top    height
Endzone  57906_000718_Endzone.mp4   372     17      279     17
Endzone  57906_000718_Endzone.mp4   851     20      273     14
Endzone  57906_000718_Endzone.mp4   853     21      271     15
Endzone  57906_000718_Endzone.mp4   855     21.     267     16
Endzone  57906_000718_Endzone.mp4   857     21.     265     17
Sideline 57906_000718_Sideline.mp4  763     18.     98      26
...
```

Sample Output, output can vary depending on removing method:

```
view     video                      left    width  top    height
Endzone  57906_000718_Endzone.mp4   372     17      279     17
Endzone  57906_000718_Endzone.mp4   851     20      273     14
Endzone  57906_000718_Endzone.mp4   857     21.     265     17
Sideline 57906_000718_Sideline.mp4  763     18.     98      26
...
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is row1 and row2? Please add the expected output

Comment: please put a simple input and a sample output

Comment: row1 and row2 are sample rows in the df. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if this is exact enough. It doesn't necessarily cut all instances that are within 1 second but some small tweaks would do the trick.  Also, I'm kind of assuming that you care more about "width/height" and "left/top" groupings than any combo of the four. Regardless, you just have to do this transform over again for any groups you really care about, up to all permutations. For the sake of brevity I left out the "left/top" grouping but it's just a repeat of this.

```
> df[df.index.isin(df[['view', 'video']].join(df[['width', 'height']]//2).drop_duplicates().index)
       view                      video  left  width  top  height
0   Endzone   57906_000718_Endzone.mp4   372   17.0  279      17
1   Endzone   57906_000718_Endzone.mp4   851   20.0  273      14
3   Endzone   57906_000718_Endzone.mp4   855   21.0  267      16
5  Sideline  57906_000718_Sideline.mp4   763   18.0   98      26
```

Answer (score 1):

Create two masks:

- For `view` and `video`: Check if previous row is the same using `.shift`+`.eq`
- For `dimensions`:  `diff` the previous row and check if  any two of it is in [-1,1]

```
col1_2_mask = df[["view","video"]].shift(1).eq(df[["view","video"]]).sum(1)<2
lwth_mask = df.iloc[:,2:].diff().isin(range(-1,2)).sum(1)<2
df[col1_2_mask | lwth_mask]
```